# Sharing a local image on Google+

Tags: ios, google-plus, file-sharing

Has anyone tried to use the code here:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share

My impression is that it makes it possible to share a URL publicly available on the net, but not a URL to a local image (that I would like to share). I hope someone will tell me I am wrong and show me why.

When I try it in order to share an image on Google+, it complains with a message saying:
"That link is invalid"

I use this kind of code to make the local URL (as I always do):
    let imageURL = NSURL(string: “MY_LOCAL_URL”

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation there are only 2 params available URL and Language Code.

So for displaying image, it will require to upload image on server, then use that URL.

I wanted to put some text also along with URL, but no documented param available. "text" param is working, but can stop work anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code way back in Google share and its working.

```
let shareBuilder = GPPShare.sharedInstance().nativeShareDialog()
GPPShare.sharedInstance().delegate = self

//URL Share
shareBuilder.setURLToShare(NSURL(string: "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg"))

//Prefilling Text    
shareBuilder.setPrefillText("Hi hello")

shareBuilder.open()
```

The URL image I entered is live on internet. Go to your Google + account and see the image is shared.

For sharing a local image we can use this

```
shareBuilder.attachImage(UIImage(named: "yourImage.png"))
```

rather than using `setURLToShare`

There are other methods in which you can attach a video too.

[image]

I have checked the code for `attachImage` and its working fine.

Comment: Interesting. But the image I want to share is local. What can I do in that case? Is it possible?

Comment: @Michel Yes you can even share the local image. Check my edited answer

Comment: OK, but can we use GPPShare without Google+ Sign-In which is deprecated?

Comment: Looking here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/ gives me the impression that your solution may be right, but not necessarily the best for future apps. What do you think?

Comment: @Michel Sdks change every month or two. We have to updated every time. Currently this is working though its deprecated. Totally depends on G+ in future.